# What are the steps to make a HTML design responsive?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, media-queries

I just learned about responsive design. My question is what steps does a HTML designer has to do to make a design responsive?

It appears that a responsive design is all about using `@media` queries and controlling the flow of elements on the page if it gets resized by setting `max-width`, `min-width` and manipulating floating, margins and padding depending on browser window's size.

Is there anything else besides `@media` query that needs to be done for responsive design?

Comment: Hate to say this, but didnt expect such a basic level question from someone with such high rep. I understand, you might be learning html now; but you have tones of tutorials and questions on SO w.r.t this and this looks like a simple google search question. And yeah, responsive means you have different css rules for different media sizes. NO hard feelings; just saying :)

Comment: Some might say what the designer has to do is to choose a good responsive library and use it.

Comment: There is no one set of steps to make a site responsive. Your question is far too broad and akin to asking 'how do I build a website'?

Comment: Hi @TheUknown. What do you mean by rep? I ask this question to learn. Thanks. :)

Answer (score 3):

**Responsive Images (different images in HTML for different situations)** is an important one.

Few important bits :

- Use of `srcset` attribute for switching between different versions of the same image.
  http://responsiveimages.org is a well of resources on this subject.
- Use of automation tools for imaging - One of my favorites is Grunt and here is a nice read about it: http://addyosmani.com/blog/generate-multi-resolution-images-for-srcset-with-grunt/

It really makes a lot of difference when user on mobile opens a page with images that are sized for it, less data and well faster loads :)

Tools like Grunt may seem like they take some work to setup but once you start working with it its so easy and fast.

More reading material:

https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/optimizing-content-efficiency/image-optimization

http://blog.cloudfour.com/responsive-hero-images/

Comment: Thanks very much Ivan68. Your answer very valuable. Helping a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely. There are three main tenants of responsive web design from Ethan Marcotte's original book, Responsive Web Design (abookapart.com/products/responsive-web-design). They are:

**1 - Fluid Grids -** percentage based widths instead of pixels for your layout/grid. This is arguably even more important than the media query as it allows websites to be fluid and not fixed. So smart phones and tablets come in too many sizes to count, so having a fluid layout makes sure your design can fit nicely at different device widths.

**2 - Flexible images -** which are basically images that shrink when the browser get smaller. There are plenty of challenges around images in the context of responsive, which is why @Ivan86 smartly recommended using the `srcset` attribute on the image tag, which I also highly recommend but also maybe wait on that until you're comfortable with the basics. Since you're just starting out, let's keep it simple with 'flexible images' which are images that are set to `max-width: 100%` with a parent container around them that is % based. This allows the image to shrink as the parent container (div, figure, etc) gets smaller. However, if you do happen to be interested in `srcset` I posted two articles on this recently: [www.richfinelli.com/srcset-part-1](http://www.richfinelli.com/srcset-part-1), http://www.richfinelli.com/srcset-part-2/ which explain how to use this new attribute.

**3 - Media queries -** as you said, are used in your css to change the layout based on available browser width.

As I think you're finding out, once you get in to responsive web design you realize there's multiple layers of challenges you can find yourself in. But I recommend buying Ethan Marcotte's book from abookapart.com to get a good jump on it. Very short and actually funny.

Comment: Thanks this answer very valuable! I only knew Media Queries. Now I know  other parts. One follow up question - can max-width substitute percentages?

Comment: For fluid layout, I only use 'max-width' of a hard pixel value on my outer-most container. And also use a width set to a percentage. Something like: .wrapper {max-width: 960px;width: 85%;}. That makes it so the width is never wider than 960px wide. So on super wide screen monitors you're never dealt a layout that is 1400px wide. But when the width is less than 960px wide you are getting a fluid layout because the width is set to 85%.

Comment: Thanks this is very good!